# How to remove whitespace from a div and all inside

Tags: html, jquery

How to remove the white space of a div and everything inside?
Asked in another way: how to apply trim or equivalent to a div and all its descendants.

- The div itself, children, and their children...
- I cannot know how many descendants the div has
- I do not know exactly what I have inside #left
- Keep the tags
- Keep the text readable with the normal spaces between words
- jQuery

jQuery. This is what I tried.

Html example (#left can have anything inside)

```js
$("#remove").click(function() {
  //only #left:
  //var text = $("#left").html();

  //only 1rst generation:
  var text = $("#left").children().html();

  var simpleText = text.trim();
  $("#check").html(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
  <div>
    <p> This is p</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="remove">Remove white space</button>
<div id="check">check</div>
```

Comment: Browsers already remove consecutive spaces. Why do you need to do so here? Can you show us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Moob: I updated. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: Why do you want this though? What is the purpose? I'm thinking that perhaps it is an xy problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following code removes all whitespace of inside #left. Is this what you have in mind?

Edit:
Thanks for the comments, I tried to refine my incorrect version, but I could not find a solution with jQuery. But this version with vanilla JS seems to work.
Also: This version uses trim and reduces multiple spaces, as I "think", that is what you are looking for.

```js
$("#remove").click(function() {
  let left = document.getElementById('left');
  
  function traverse(node) {
    node.childNodes.forEach(child => {
        if(child.nodeType == 1) {
          // recurse if the node is a tag
          traverse(child);
        }
        if(child.nodeType == 3) {
          let textContent = child.textContent;
          // check if the text node has content, other than whitespace
          if(/\S/.test(textContent)) {
            let trimmed = child.textContent.trim();
            let singled = trimmed.replace(/ +/g, ' ');
            child.textContent = singled;
          }
        }
    })
  }
  
  traverse(left);
});

$("#show").click(function() {
   $('#preview').text($('#left').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">
<div>
    <p> This is  p</p>
    <div>
      <p> Another   p <span> with a span</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<button id="remove">Trim</button>
 | 
<button id="show">Show HTML</button>

<pre id="preview">

</pre>
```

Comment: Did you run your code?   The first .replace removes all HTML - so might as well be just `$("#left").text($("#left").text().replace...)`

Comment: replace(/\s*/g, ''); removes the space between words. The text is not readable

Comment: Also `.text()` will always be truthy.   You could change `if($el.text())` to `if($el.children().length == 0) {`

Comment: @Nrc that's **exactly what you asked for** - the browser already collapses multiple spaces (as seen in this snippet before clicking the button - compare the HTML with the output).  Perhaps you could update your question to include an **expected output**

Comment: @Nrc Your attempt uses `.trim()` which removes leading/trailing whitespace only (rather than *all* whitespace) - surely its not so hard to extrapolate this answer to use `.trim()` instead of `.replace`?    They key here is the loop.  It still may not work, but don't just dismiss out of hand because they've followed your instruction.

Comment: @freedomn-m: I have updated the question. Let me know if Its not clear